# Determine the radius of of the converges of the power series and find its analytic formula

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Determine the radius of of the converges of the power series and find its analytic formula

$$f(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{x^n}{n(n-1)}$$

i know that radius of converges is '1' but what mean to find analytic formula for power series can any help

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
If you differentiate it twice, you might see something easier to deal with:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{n-2}=1+x+x^2+\ldots$$
which in turn is the series for another function. After you find that function, you can integrate twice to get back $f$.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{n-1}=-\log(1-x)$, now you may do basic integration to $-\log(1-x)$ to retrieve $f$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n(n-1)}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n-1}-
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}n=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n+x-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$
and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n$  should be a familiar function...